# End chain of deferred computation with normal value

Tags: web-scraping, ocaml

I want the the function below to take an url and return a soup node using `lambdasoup`, in other words I want the type to be:  `val do_get : string -> soup node = <fun>`. With the bind operator `(>>=)` I can wait for a computation to finish but this always returns another deferred computation. I'd like to be able to end chain by turning a deferred computation into normal value. What can I do?

```
let do_get url = 
  let uri = Uri.of_string url in
  Cohttp_async.Client.get uri
  >>= fun (_, body) -> 
    Cohttp_async.Body.to_string body
  >>= fun s -> parse s
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Deferred.peek` to go from the deferred value to a normal value. And around the beginning if your program you need to call `Scheduler.go`, probably like this `never_returns (Scheduler.go ())`.

There is a chapter in real world ocaml which explains how to use the async library
https://dev.realworldocaml.org/concurrent-programming.html